# Inscribing a parabola tangent to two equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I found a [geometry question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726348/two-juxtaposed-equilateral-triangles-with-joined-lines) posted today very interesting and would like to clear a doubt regarding a parabola if it can be inscribed (as described below).

Setup :
Two equilateral triangles $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle CDE$ stand on
$\overline{BD}$ as shown. $AD, BE$ intersect at $F$. Show that $FC^2 = AF \cdot EF$

[image]

If tangents at two points $A,E$ on the parabola meet at $C$, $F$ being the focus of parabola, then $FC^2=AF \cdot EF$ holds.
Now if I try to inscribe a parabola in the region of $\angle ACE$ such that it is tangent to $AC$ at $A$ and $CE$ at $E$, does the condition $FC^2=AF \cdot EF$ uniquely identifies $F$ as focus of such a parabola, or are there more than one parabola with different focus
also possible?

I thought that five conditions should uniquely determine any conic. Those known conditions here are points $A,E$, tangents at $A,E$ and the property that $FA, FC, FE$ are in geometric progression. But I am not sure if this direction of last condition is sufficient since perhaps we can find $F'$ somewhere else for which similar triangles $AF'C, CF'E$ can be made, and $F'$ will become the focus of second such parabola.

> > **To be precise**, can somebody suggest a proof for the converse of the property that if $FC^2 = AF \cdot FE$, where $AC, EC$ are tangents to the parabola, then $F$ must be the focus of such parabola.

Here is one such parabola with focus $F$ and meeting above conditions.

[image]

Bonus for those interested in a fun challenge in this setup, not related to the problem above :

> Let $BE$ cut $AC$ in $P$ and $AD$ cut $CE$ in $Q$. Given $AF = 4, FC = 6$, calculate with proof, $BP + DQ$.
>  Answer : $19$

Comment: Nice challenge. There's a "one-liner" explanation using the congruent triangles and   $FC^2$ identity. $\quad$ You might want to restructure the question so that it's focused on the doubt, instead of the context.

Comment: @CalvinLin The tricky part is proving $PCQ$ is equilateral. Indeed I want the converse proof, I will highlight so.

Comment: Not that tricky if you know the congruent triangles map. That $60^\circ$ rotation about $C$ takes lines $BE$ to $AD$ and lines (not as points) $AC$ to $CE$, hence by considering the intersections of these lines, take $P$ to $Q$. Thus $PC=CQ$ (and hence $PCQ$ is equilateral).

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh now I see it, benefits of rotation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the converse is false: there are infinitely many points $F$ such that $FC^2=AF\cdot FE$, but only one of them is the focus of the parabola tangent to lines $AC$, $EC$ at points $A$, $E$ respectively.

To see why, choose any point $P$ on $AC$ and construct $Q$ on $EC$ such that
$$
CQ:QE=AP:PC.
$$
We can then construct the [circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Circle_of_Apollonius) through $P$ whose points have all the same ratio of distances from $A$ and $C$, and also the circle of Apollonius through $Q$ whose points have all the same ratio of distances from $C$ and $E$. If $F$ is an intersection of those circles, then:
$$
AF:FC=AP:PC=CQ:QE=FC:FE
$$
and consequently $FC^2=AF\cdot FE$.

Varying the position of $P$ we can thus construct many points having that property. But only one of them is the focus $G$ of the parabola tangent to lines $AC$, $EC$ at points $A$, $E$, which is uniquely determined.

[image]

EDIT.

We can construct the focus $G$ of the parabola as follows. Draw a line $r$ through $C$ and through the midpoint of $AE$: this line is parallel to the axis [by a property of the parabola](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ArchimedesTriangle.shtml).

Draw two lines $s$, $t$ parallel to $r$ and passing through $A$, $E$ respectively. By [the reflective property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Alternative_proofs) of the parabola, the reflection of $s$ about the tangent at $A$ passes through the focus, and the same is true for the reflection of $t$ about the tangent at $E$. Hence focus $G$ is the intersection of those reflected lines.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So the tangent parabola is unique but to determine its focus $G$, the ratio $AG : GC$ should be known - did I understand it correct? (Because we are varying $P$, we are essentially varying the ratio $AF:FC$)

Comment: @MyMolecules I added a construction for focus $G$.

Comment: N.B. The "five constraints" rule holds for a generic conic. Knowing it is a parabola reduces the number to four.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for nice insights : a) "$h^2=ab$ reduces number of constraints to $4$ b) Reflecting two diameters in respective tangents gives focal radii; their intersection gives focus!